# How to use the Compute to calculate the total with Double Datatype

Tags: vb.net, type-conversion

I have expression string:

```
dim str as string = "999999999 * 999999999"
```

I use DataTable.Compute to calculate:

```
dim dt as new datatable
dim result as double = 0
result = cdbl(dt.Compute(str))
```

And I get an error:

```
Value is either too large or too small for Type 'Int32'.
```

How can I control result datatype in this case?
**Solution:**
This function work like Windows's Calculator. Code so confuse but it work :)

```
'input = "999,999,999 x 888,888,888 + 112,365 ÷ 15 − 987,653"
 Public Shared Function strCalc(ByVal input As String) As String
    If input.Substring(input.Length - 1, 1) = " " Then input = input.Substring(0, input.Length - 3)
    input = input.Replace("−", "-").Replace("x", "*").Replace("÷", "/").Replace(",", "")
    Dim temp As Double = 0
    Dim arr() As String = input.Split(" ")

    If arr.Length > 1 Then
        temp = New DataTable().Compute(If(arr(0).Contains("."), arr(0), arr(0) & ".0") & " " & arr(1) & " " &
                                       If(arr(2).Contains("."), arr(2), arr(2) & ".0"), "")
        If arr.Length > 3 Then
            For i As Integer = 3 To arr.Length - 1 Step 2
                temp = New DataTable().Compute(temp & " " & arr(i) & " " &
                                               If(arr(i + 1).Contains("."), arr(i + 1), arr(i + 1) & ".0"), "")
            Next
        End If
        Return temp
    End If
    Return input
End Function
```

Comment: Firstly, you can do this in one line, i.e. `Dim result = CDbl(New DataTable().Compute(str))`.  As for the question, I'd imagine that using `999999999.0` would work.

Comment: For me compute API is expecting one more parameter named filter. How come your code is even compiling?

Comment: Or more easily: `Dim result As Double = 999999999R * 999999999R`. "R" is a type character for `Double` in visual basic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runtime is treating your expression `999999999 * 999999999` as a multiplication of two integer values, and trying to return it as an object which is the return type of `Compute` API. The output of multiplication of those numbers is resulting in a very large value which is crossing the maximum value which can be stored in a variable of `int` (`System.Int32`) data type.

It results in arithmetic overflow exception. To give a hint to the runtime so that it considers the expression as a multiplication of two `double` numbers please use following code:

```
dim str as string = "999999999.0 * 999999999.0"
```

Comment: `999999999.0 * 999999999` or `999999999 * 999999999.0` is also okay.

Comment: Yes. Right @Ajay. Run time upgrades the expression based on the operand with higher precision. Float has higher precision than integer data type. So upgrading either of the two operands to float will upgrade the whole expression as a multiplication of two float operands.